# How do I record a video of my iPhone app from the simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using OSX mountain lion, and I have been able to record a video using quick time to screen capture, but it does not record the sound generated from the iOS Simulator, but rather from the microphone.

I want to record audio and video from the iOS Simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You could:
  - try a professional screen recording software (Camtasia, Screenflow,...)
  - use a virtual sound output device that captures the sound and writes it to disk
  - connect your sound output to your input (using a Cinch cable)

See http://bit.ly/UXBJ9N for more info on the latter two.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using sound flower (which I can't praise enough - it was much more simple than I expected - and tiny app size too) to capture audio, and a random screen capture utility to capture video, then I married them up in a video editing application. Not perfect, but it works.

I will post here if I find a simpler solution, because despite all the blog posts about this matter, I could not find something ideal.